# Tracking file usage in Minio

Tags: minio

Is there any way to track usage of files in a Minio storage?

If I could trigger a script (that will keep and periodically write file usage info in a database), then I could find files that have not been used for a very long time (e.g. 1-2 year).

I want to perform periodical cleanup on buckets that are used for temporary files.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using bucket notification. Read more about it here https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-bucket-notification-guide.html#PostgreSQL